# Google maps javascript api services crashing in phonegap when connection is unstable

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Unstable connection in a normal browser is not a major issue because the user can click on the "reload button" if the page didn't load properly. In phonegap there is no such button, so we have to make sure everythings loads correctly 100% of the time.

I experience a problem because when connection is unstable during the initialisation of a google service (places autocompletion, geocoding or map display), no error message is thrown and yet the service will NOT work.

First we initialize google services

```
//In this senario the internet connection is good and stable
$('body').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places&amp;v=3.exp&callback=googleCallback"></script>');
```

Then we want to use the google places autocomplete service and here is a scenario that is reproducible :

```
//At this point we lose the internet connection
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete'));
//At this point autocomplete is defined and not empty, no error thrown
//At this point the internet connection come back
//At this point the autocomplete box is not working
```

Note that this "bug" also occurs for geocoding and map display.

The first part of my question is : how can i at least detect in my code that the initialisation of the (autocomplete or geocoding or display map) service didn't work properly.

Now we would like to reload the places autocomplete because internet is back and we need the service

```
//From now on the connection is good and stable
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete'));
//We get no error but the autocomplete box still does not work
```

Here is the only way i found to get the places autocomplete service to work after connection loss occured as shown in scenario 1

```
//From now on the connection is good and stable
$('body').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places&amp;v=3.exp&callback=googleCallback"></script>');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete'));
//At this point the autocomplete box is working properly
```

So the second part of my question is, do i really have to reload the hole google maps javascript api when 1 particular service failed to initialize ?

To reproduce the bug you can follow that [link](http://www.kankaroo.com/html/debug001.html), it is referenced as problem 3.

If you're intersted in problem 1 you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33880420/how-to-load-google-maps-javascript-api-in-phonegap-being-robust-to-connection-un)
If you're intersted in problem 2 you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33881846/google-maps-javascript-api-crashing-in-phonegap-when-connection-is-unstable)