# Google maps javascript api crashes in phonegap [Hard topic]

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm facing problems when the client internet connection is unstable. If disconnections occur during the loading process google maps services won't work even when the connection comes back.

The difficulty with phonegap compared to a normal browser is that there is no "reload page" button the user can hit if the page didn't load properly. We thus have to ensure a 100% safe load.

If you follow the instructions provided by Google to implement google maps javascript api in your phonegap app, the loading process will crash at three different steps if the client connection is unstable.

Each crash is independent and a bit complex to explain, so i created sub questions : [first crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33880420/how-to-load-google-maps-javascript-api-in-phonegap-being-robust-to-connection-un), [second crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33881846/google-maps-javascript-api-crashing-in-phonegap-when-connection-is-unstable), [third crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883210/google-maps-javascript-api-services-crashing-in-phonegap-when-connection-is-unst)

I also created that [file](http://www.kankaroo.com/html/debug001.html) so that anyone can reproduce the crashes.

I suspect that the problem partly comes from google's script, but there is probably a work around i didn't see.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure at all that this could help but I faced an issue regarding multiDex when I tryed to use google map api when adding this code in file build-extras.gradle my google map crash was solved :

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

What I understood was that using simple Dex I can only implement 65000 method but the google api add lot of them. 
[Building Apps with Over 65K Methods](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)
Not sure this could help or not, let me know if I should delete this answer.